# jquery getting removed dynamic row value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using below code I am adding all values of input filed.
but when I remove dynamic row this piece of code still getting 
the old removed row value.
How I can fix it ? 
I don't need remove row value.

MyCode

```
$(document).on('blur',"input[name$='[credit]']", function () {
    var totalCredit = 0;
    $("input[name$='[credit]']").each(function() 
     {
        if ($(this).attr('name') && $(this).attr('name').match(/items\[\d+\]\[credit\]/)) 
        {
            totalCredit += $(this).val() ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0; // get exchange_rate
        }

         console.log(" Current value: " +    $(this).val() );

     });// end each.

     console.log(" Total: " +    totalCredit );


     // assign total to div id.
     $("#totalCredit").html("Credit:" + delimitNumbers(totalCredit) );
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with `remove` ?? may be hide not remove  .. anyway we will see try to use `$("input[name$='[credit]']:visible")` instead of `$("input[name$='[credit]']")` if you get the right total so your remove word means hide

Comment: :visible seems working fine post a answer below so I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*but when I remove dynamic row this piece of code still getting the old removed row value* >> if this is the case so your element just hide not removed from the DOM

So you can try to use `:visible` selector to select just the visible rows not the hidden one

```
$("input[name$='[credit]']:visible")
```

instead of

```
$("input[name$='[credit]']")
```

Comment: adding visible with $("input[name$='[credit]']").each(function()  seems working fine.Thanks